# Call MainActivity function from another class as MainActivity

Tags: java, android

I want to reload MainActivity after data change. So I wrote this code and it working well.

This is from MainActivity, that i want to reload:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
private static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;
LinearLayout horizontalForecast, todayForecast, tomorrowForecast;
TextView ViewSunRise, ViewSunSet, NowTatva, NextTejas, Longitude, Latitude, BeziT, TatvicForecast;
TextView Today, Tomorrow, NextTatva;
GPSTracker gps;
ImageView img;
TabHost th;

public void reload() {
    finish();
    Intent i2 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivityForResult(i2, RESULT_SETTINGS);
}
}
```

But when I call this from another Class (not an activity), it doesn't work.

This is from another Class:

```
package com.reversity.simpletatva;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

MainActivity MA;
boolean ch = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location = null; // location
double latitude = Double.NaN; // latitude
double longitude = Double.NaN; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

protected static final int RESULT_SETTINGS = 1;

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            // First get location from Network Provider
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS není zapnuta, lokace byla nastavena na 0. Chcete přejít do nastavení nebo nastavit vlastní?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Nastavení", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Použít vlastní", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            Intent i = new Intent(mContext, Preference.class);
            mContext.startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    /*
    Toast changed = Toast.makeText(mContext, "Location changes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    changed.show();
    MA.reload();
    startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MainActivity.class));
    invalidate();
    */
    stopUsingGPS();
    MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity ();
    mainActivity.reload();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

public Boolean locChanged(){
    return ch;

}

}
```

So I want to Reload `MainActivity` from `GPSTracker Class` when `onLocationChanged();`
I don't find answer that will be usefull for me. So I ask this question. Don't blame me.

I just need how can I call the `MainActivity` to reload from `GPSTracker Class`.
I tried everything I know. But it isn't working and Aplication will close.

Error `NullPointerException`

Comment: What is your requirement..?

Comment: What are you really trying to do? Reloading an activity from another java class?

Comment: Yes. I want to reload `MainActivity` from another `class`

Comment: @Dhanielk why..That is what we are asking..? If you tell the reason we may suggest you alternative...

Comment: what doesn't happen? r u getting error? what do u want? do u want that, activity2 close and mainactivity to start ?

Comment: Sorry guys. `Activity2` isn't an `Activity` it's a `Class`. I want to call from `this class` to `MainActivity` to reload it. But I getting `NullPointerExeption` error and aplication will fall.

Comment: Lets get things straight here.. Are the second class an `Activity` or not? Because you say its not, yet it extends `Activity`. If its just a  generic class, there is no need for extending `Activity`

Comment: Actually I do think `Activity2` is an `Activity` => `Activity2 extends Activity`.  See vikingsteve's answer about static/non-static contexts and how to get around it. However the question is what is your logic behind - because you can do it this way but to me it occurs you want to do something else and this problem only occurs as following the wrong path (to the dark side..)

Comment: OK. as I wrot I say it's only `Example`. I have Class when `onChange` I call `MainActivity` for reload. But it doesn't work, because of `NullPointerExeption`.

Comment: Posting your actually code would be lot better then this example code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what you can do just add this in the Androidmanifest.xml file where you declared your main activity inside the activity tag

```
  android:finishOnTaskLaunch="true"
```

and remove `finish();` from the reload method.

Now in GPSTracker class just start the activity by calling

```
Intent intent=new Intent(mContext,MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mContext.startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: This is working, but I have another problem. I go to inf loop because in main I call GPSTracker and and he call reload :D

Comment: ya that will be because onLocationChange will be called whenever your location will change please tell the exact requirement so that I can suggest you the better way to acquire that.

Comment: Ok. I think I will made another Class for this .. Because I want to call reload only one time. Or just reload MainActivity every 2 minutes. that will be best way I think.

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call a non-static method from a static context.

Either make your `reload` method static, or use a reference to an instance of MainActivity (e.g. `MainActivity myActivity; myActivity.reload()`)

Alternatively, perhaps you meant for Activity2 to extend MainActivity?

Comment: Why downvote? `MainActivity.reload()` will only work if `reload` is `static`. Don't blame a right answer for a poorly asked question!

Comment: I can't make `reload();` `static`. Because it doesn't work (`finish();` `startActivityForResult();`)

Comment: Ok, well, then you need a reference to an instance of MainActivity! Your 'other class', does it have a `MainActivity` field or another easy way to access an instance of `MainActivity`?

Comment: I have reference just like MainActivity MC; and using like this MC.reload(); ... but I think error is in `reload();` because when I call it from MainActivity it works very well. But when I call it from other class it doesn't work.

Comment: Resolved with method that post pyus13. Error was `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass the second class a reference to `MainActivity`, and call `reload()` on that reference.

For a generic class:

```
public class SecondClass {

    MainActivity mActivity;

    // Constructor where you pass a reference to MainActivity
    public SecondClass(Activity activity) {
        mActivity = activity;
    }

    public onChange() {
        mActivity.reload();
    }
}
```

When you initialize the `SecondClass` in `MainActivity` you pass a reference to `MainActivity`

```
SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass(this);
```

Then you can use `onChange()`, and `MainActivity.reload()` should get called.

```
secondClass.onChange();
```

**EDIT:**

Well, now that you updated your question, my answer is no longer correct. Since your second class is a `Service`, keeping references to your `MainActivity` might create memory leaks.

I would solve this with registering a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `MainActivity`. In your `Service`, you broadcast an `Intent` when an updated is needed.

This would look something like this:
In `MainActivity`:

```
public void MainActivity extends Activity {
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       .
       .
       .

       // We listen for a broadcasted Intent with 
       // action = com.example.ACTION_RELOAD_MAINACTIVITY
       IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
       filter.addAction("com.example.ACTION_RELOAD_MAINACTIVITY");

       // Init the receiver
       mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
           @Override
           public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {                   
               // Reload when we receive the broadcast
               MainActivity.this.reload();
           }
       }

       // Register the receiver
       registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    // In onDestroy() we unregister the receiver
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mReceiver);
    }
}
```

In your `Service`, you now have to broadcast an `Intent` when you want to reload `MainActivity`.

```
public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {
    .
    .
    .

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Create an Intent with 
        // action = com.example.ACTION_RELOAD_MAINACTIVITY
        Intent i = new Intent("com.example.ACTION_RELOAD_MAINACTIVITY");  

        // As a side note; You can use this Intent to send data to MainActivity.
        // If you want to pass the Location object of onLocationChanged() to
        // MainActivity, you would simply call i.putExtra("current_location", location) 
        // The data can then be fetched using the supplied Intent in onReceive().

        // Broadcast that Intent
        sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

Comment: I've just started to write it... you were faster :)

Comment: Ok ok. but when secondClass is in own Java file?

Comment: `Intent i = new Intent("com.example.ACTION_RELOAD_MAINACTIVITY"); ` How it would like when I have package com.example.something and Activity -> MainActivity?? I will looks like this? 
        `Intent i = new Intent("com.example.something.MainActivity");  `

Comment: Thank you very much. But I get `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Dhanielk The String inside `Intent()` is called the Intent action. It should "describe" the general action that will be performed by the Intent. So if I want to describe the action of an `Intent` that updates my `ListView`, I could use action `"ACTION_UPDATE_LISTVIEW"`.   But it can be whatever you like, ex. `new Intent("myAction123")`. Normal convention is to use `"com.yourpackage.yourapp.ACTION_theaction"` where `theaction` describes what actions this `Intent` performes.

As for the `NullPointerException`, I need to know where it happens...

Comment: Resolved with method that post pyus13. Error was `NullPointerException` when I was using `"com.reversity.simpletatva.MainActivity"`